# GDPR cookie bar, auto accept when changing pages

Tags: gdpr, european-union, cookies

Can i add a GDPR cookie bar on home page that will allow the users to accept or rejects the cookies but to also write on the bar something like:

"You agree accept all cookies if you switch to another page"?

When the user will change the page the cookies will be accepted automatically and the bar wont be displayed anymore.

Is this legal?

Thanks

Comment: Such implied consent used to be common in the pre-GPDR times, e.g. "by continuing to use the site, you agree to XXX. Click here for choices". However, GDPR defines consent as an "unambiguous indication of the data subject’s wishes" given "by a statement or by a clear affirmative action". All data protection authorities have updated their guidance accordingly, and the need for a confirming action was affirmed by the CJEU In *Planet 49*. Most authorities also reject any dark patterns, and expect agree/decline to be offered equally prominently.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not adequate for either the so-called 'cookie law' (the ePrivacy Directive, the law pertaining to storing data on the user's device) or GDPR (if the lawfulness of processing personal data is based on consent).

[european-union](/questions/tagged/european-union) guidance (my emphasis):

> A consent request needs to be presented in a clear and concise way, using language that is easy to understand, and be clearly distinguishable from other pieces of information such as terms and conditions. The request has to specify what use will be made of your personal data and include contact details of the company processing the data. **Consent must be freely given, specific, informed and unambiguous**. ...

- https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rights-citizens/how-my-personal-data-protected/how-should-my-consent-be-requested_en

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) guidance:

> Consent should be obvious and require a positive action to opt in. Consent requests must be prominent, unbundled from other terms and conditions, concise and easy to understand, and user-friendly. ...
>
> You must ask people to actively opt in. Don’t use pre-ticked boxes, opt-out boxes or other default settings. Wherever possible, give separate (‘granular’) options to consent to different purposes and different types of processing. ...

https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/uk-gdpr-guidance-and-resources/lawful-basis/a-guide-to-lawful-basis/lawful-basis-for-processing/consent/#ib4

Comment: I understand, but can i add a interstitial banner when a user is switching a page with a button "accept cookies and proceed" and a link "settings"?

Comment: You may not set cookies without freely given, specific, informed and unambiguous consent from the user. You may have such a banner so long as you don't set cookies without that consent.

Comment: If your question is, "may I prevent people from using the website unless they accept cookies?" my understanding is no you may not, although some companies do it. If this is for a business you ought to invest in competent legal advice.

Comment: https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/direct-marketing-and-privacy-and-electronic-communications/guide-to-pecr/guidance-on-the-use-of-cookies-and-similar-technologies/how-do-we-comply-with-the-cookie-rules/#comply12

Comment: Thank you guys!